# WMI access denied from one day to the other

Tags: powershell, windows-xp, wmi

I had a working WMI connection for months. From a W10 Server I check a dozen XP clients.
From one day to the other on, one particular machine denies access. All the others that should be identical do work normal.

The error I get:

```
[10.1.1.1] Connecting to remote server 10.1.1.1 failed with the following error message: Access is denied. 
For more information see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo         : OpenError: (10.1.1.1:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied, PSSessionStateBroken
```

System is running XP SP3
No access to internet

Things I've checked:

- Trusted hosts
- Test-WSMan (service is running)
- DCOM permission
- Permission for the user to the WMI namespace
- Verify WMI Impersonation Rights
- Login Credentials
- Remote Desktop connection (works)
- Enter-PSSession (does not work)
- Invoke-Command localhost (works)

What could have changed or I could additionally test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the time difference between Host and Client.

As there is not Time sync server in my network and the system is not connected to the internet the local times can differ by a lot.

here it was off by multiple days.